# Transmission of video and audio signals

Tags: mars, insight, data-transmission, video, audio

I know this is a silly question.In july,2019 NASA's insight captured sound by wind gusts.Here is a link of video that shows the movement of robotic arms and sound of wind on mars.

So my question is:
Did NASA receive both the sound wave and the  video simultaneously or they are later synced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video and audio were not packaged in the same file: InSight did not produce a video file with audio tracks. As you can see in the screenshot, the 'audio' was recorded by the seismometer instrument (SEIS) as vibration data.

This can be converted to audio (after all, audio is also vibration data), but this was done after reception. NASA [did some processing](https://soundcloud.com/nasa/quake-sol-173) to get usable audio:

> Far below the human range of hearing, this sonification from SEIS had to be sped up and slightly processed to be audible through headphones.

The video and audio may have been sent in the same batch (InSight stores its data, and usually [uploads to an orbiting satellite](https://www.seis-insight.eu/en/public-2/the-insight-mission/insight-lander) 1-2 times a day), so they may have been received 'simultaneously'.